# C# WebClient.UploadData in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a c# method that I'm trying to convert to ruby on rails . I'm using unirest but I think something is not working correctly. This is my C# method :

```
private static string HTTPPoster(string url, string prmSendData)
        {
            try
            {
                WebClient wUpload = new WebClient();
                wUpload.Proxy = null;
                Byte[] bPostArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(prmSendData);
                Byte[] bResponse = wUpload.UploadData(url, "POST", bPostArray);
                Char[] sReturnChars = Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(bResponse);
                string sWebPage = new string(sReturnChars);
                return sWebPage;
            }
            catch
            {
                return "-1";
            }
        }
```

And This is what I tried so far in rails with unirest :

```
def HTTPPoster(url)

    xml = "My XML Goes Here"

    byte_array = xml.bytes

    headers = {}
    headers['Content-Type'] =  "application/json"
    headers['Accept'] = "application/json"

    response = Unirest.post(url,
      headers: headers,
      parameters: {
        body: byte_array
      })

    puts "response #{response.body}"

    if ![200,201].include?(response.code)
      raise "Mblox Error: #{response.code}, #{response.body}"
    end
  end
```

If you also know other libraries that can achieve what I need please let me know.

Comment: What is not working correctly? Are you receiving any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Faraday gem and sent the data as xml and not as byte array. And now I am achieving want I wanted.

```
response = Faraday.post(url) do |req|
      req.headers['Content-Type'] =  "application/xml"
      req.headers['Accept'] =  "*/*"
      req.headers['Accept-Encoding'] =  "gzip, deflate, br"
      req.body = xml
end
```